# Python JSON decoding error TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, json

Hi there i am coding in python trying to make a user friendly currency exchange app for a school project but have encountered and error with trying to decode json for the exchange rates.
The code i'm using is:

```
import urllib.request
import json
(str) = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=FRM&to=TO&q=AM";
(str) = (str.replace("FRM", "GBP"))
(str) = (str.replace("TO", "USD"))
url = (str.replace("AM", "20"))
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = (f.read(100))
print (data)
json_input = data
decoded = json.loads(json_input)
print ("conversion is: ", decoded["v"])
```

and the error that i am getting is:

```
b'{"to": "USD", "rate": 1.66215, "from": "GBP", "v": 33.243000000000002}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jay\My Cubby\get qure.py", line 12, in <module>
decoded = json.loads(json_input)
File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 309, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 352, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

So i was just wondering if anyone had any ideas of how to fix this error? Or if anyone has seen this error before?
Thanks in advance for any help
J.Rymer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Python 3, you need to *decode* the `bytes` return value from `urllib.request.urlopen()` to a unicode string:

```
decoded = json.loads(json_input.decode('utf8'))
```

This makes the assumption that the web service you are using is using the default JSON encoding of UTF-8.

You could check the response for a character set if you don't want to assume:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
charset = f.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
data = f.read()
decoded = json.loads(data.decode(charset))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce! And it works 100% so thanks :)

Comment: The first `decoded` code snippet worked for me in `django-rest-framework` testing. Thanks