# TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object, api

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x, urllib

```
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse

Name = 'BagFullOfHoles' #Random player
Platform = 'xone'#pc, xbox, xone, ps4, ps3

url = 'http://api.bfhstats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=' + Platform + '&name=' + Name
json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj)
print (data)
```

TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Just recently used 2to3.py and this error or others come up when I try to fix it . Anyone with any pointers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python JSON decoding error TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359997/python-json-decoding-error-typeerror-cant-use-a-string-pattern-on-a-bytes-like). As the first answer states, _"In Python 3, you need to decode the `bytes` return value from `urllib.request.urlopen()` to a unicode string"_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)` returns an HTTPResponse object.  We need to `read()` the response bytes in, and then `decode()` those bytes to a string as follows:

```
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse

Name = 'BagFullOfHoles' #Random player
Platform = 'xone'#pc, xbox, xone, ps4, ps3

url = 'http://api.bfhstats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=' + Platform + '&name=' + Name
json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
string = json_obj.read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)
print (json_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3, as you may know, has separate `bytes` and `str` types. Reading from a file opened in binary mode will return `bytes` objects.

The `json.load()` function only works with files (and file-like objects) opened in text mode (as opposed to binary mode). It appears that `urllib.request.urlopen()` will return a file-like in binary mode.

Instead of using `json.load()`, consider reading from the `HTTPResponse` object and decoding, then passing to `json.loads()`, like this:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    json_str = f.read().decode()
obj = json.loads(json_str)
```

Alternatively, you may wish to investigate the [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).